Log4j2 configuration XML schema does not allow the <Route></Route> block to accept nested elements
I am designing a logging mechanism for my server where each user will have their own log folder named after their employeeId, and the log files within each folder are named after the dates. To achieve this, I was advised to use Log4j <Routing> mechanism. However, even though I have put down everything as told by the document, the XML editor (Visual Studio Code) keeps saying the <Route></Route> block does not accept a nested document. The following is my xml configuration:
<Configuration xmlns="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns/log4j-config-2.xsd"
               status="WARN">
               <Appenders>

                    <Routing name="AppAppender">
                        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:employeeId}">
                            <Route>
                                <RollingFile name="EmployeeLogAppender" fileName="${baseLogDir}/${ctx:employeeId}/log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                                        filePattern="${baseLogDir}/${ctx:employeeId}/archive/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log">
                                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                                    <Policies>
                                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                                    </Policies>
                                </RollingFile>
                            </Route>
                        </Routes>
                    </Routing>

                    <Routing name="WebAppender">
                        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:layer}">
                            <Route>
                                <RollingFile name="CustomerLogAppender" fileName="${baseLogDir}/${ctx:employeeId}/log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                                        filePattern="${baseLogDir}/archive/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}/${ctx:layer}.log">
                                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                                    <Policies>
                                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                                    </Policies>
                                </RollingFile>
                            </Route>
                        </Routes>
                    </Routing>

               </Appenders>
               <Loggers>

                    <Logger name="com.example.main.Controller">
                        <AppenderRef ref="AppAppender"></AppenderRef>
                        <AppenderRef ref="WebAppender"></AppenderRef>
                    </Logger>

                    <Logger name="com.example.main.Service">
                        <AppenderRef ref="AppAppender"></AppenderRef>
                        <AppenderRef ref="WebAppender"></AppenderRef>
                    </Logger>

                    <Logger name="org.springframework.data.mongodb">
                        <AppenderRef ref="AppAppender"></AppenderRef>
                        <AppenderRef ref="WebAppender"></AppenderRef>
                    </Logger>

                    <Logger name="org.mongodb.driver">
                        <AppenderRef ref="AppAppender"></AppenderRef>
                        <AppenderRef ref="WebAppender"></AppenderRef>
                    </Logger>

               </Loggers>
</Configuration>

The following is the error message displayed by VSC:
cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'Route' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.xml(cvc-complex-type.2.1)

I have tried to look into the schema for the <Route> element. According to the schema, the <Route> element could only contain a ref and key attribute:
<complexType name="org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.Route">
<annotation>
<documentation>A Route to an appender.</documentation>
</annotation>
<attribute name="key" type="string">
<annotation>
<documentation>The key.</documentation>
</annotation>
</attribute>
<attribute name="ref" type="string">
<annotation>
<documentation>The Appender reference.</documentation>
</annotation>
</attribute>
</complexType>

However, this is what mentioned by the documentation:

The Route element determines the appender to use if the route is selected. The appender can be:

A previously declared appender, from the Appenders section of the configuration file.

A new appender that is instantiated based on a nested appender definition, when the route becomes active.



I have tried changing the schema to different versions, nothing has worked so far. Should I just ignore the message? Does the schema validation matter? Thank you very much


I have tried changing the schema to different versions, nothing has worked so far. Should I just ignore the message? Does the schema validation matter?

The configuration of Log4j Core is schema-less, so you can ignore the validation errors. The schemas available at https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns are automatically generated at each release by an internal tool called Log4j Docgen and cover the basic features of a Log4j Core configuration.
Advanced features such as:

Property substitution, which allows you to put a ${...} placeholder instead of the value of a configuration attribute.
Arbiters, which allow you to preprocess the configuration tree, based on external variables.
Lazy nodes, such as .

either can not be expressed in terms of an XSD schema or the Log4j Docgen tool does not know how to express them.
Third-party Log4j plugins are also not recognized by the XSD schema.
Log4j Docgen is basically an advanced annotation processor and the only information it can extract for the <Route> plugin is that it has a ref and key attribute and some yet to be parsed content:
@PluginFactory
public static Route createRoute(
        @PluginAttribute("ref") final String appenderRef,
        @PluginAttribute("key") final String key,
        @PluginNode final Node node);


Thank you very much! I was quite worried since the schema and the documentation were conflicting. Now I just ignore the schema
